# Custom Tableview cell with multiline UILabel needs dynamic height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder

I created a custom TableView cell with Interface Builder. This is what it looks like:

[image: IB Custom Table Cell]

For the Description Label, I need that to word wrap so I set it as such:

[image: Settings for Description Label]

In my SettingsPageViewController, I have the following Table View methods overridden:

```
@implementation SBSettingsViewController
{
    NSArray *settingHeaders;
    NSArray *settingDescriptions;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self setupLeftMenuButton];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
settingHeaders = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Label Header 1",@"Label Header 2",nil];
settingDescriptions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Two line description Two line description Two line description ",@"One Line Description",nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [settingHeaders count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SettingsTableCell";

SettingsTableViewCell *cell = (SettingsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SettingsTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.settingsHeaderLabel.text = [settingHeaders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.settingsDescriptionLabel.text = [settingDescriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.settingsDescriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.settingsDescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
CGRect appFrame=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
cell.settingsDescriptionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = appFrame.size.width - 15;

[cell.settingsDescriptionLabel sizeToFit];
[cell.settingsDescriptionLabel setNeedsDisplay];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 85;
}
```

Here is what the resulting page looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the description label for the 1st tableview cell does NOT word wrap. It just cuts off. **How do I make it wrap?**

Also, I'd like for the Tableview cell height to be dynamically adjusted. I tried to change the heightForRowAtIndexPath: to be UITableViewAutomaticDimension but that just made it look super weird as such:

[image]

**How do I get the tableview height adjusted for the row with the 1 line description label is slightly shorter?**

Thanks you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sizeToFit() returns wrong height - Need to find cell width in heightForRow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731721/sizetofit-returns-wrong-height-need-to-find-cell-width-in-heightforrow)

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724783/how-do-i-create-dynamic-views-in-swift/34726428#34726428

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give constraint of header label top, leading, trailing to super view and bottom (vertical ) to description Label.
same for description label >  leading, trailing  and bottom margin to super view.

now set Header label height Fix and description label make multiline ( Lines = 0)

for table view set in viewDidLoad

```
_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Let me know if this works...

Comment: Beginner Question: how do I get my tableView hooked up from my XIB file so that the ViewController can access it? 

I have dataSource and delegate connected to File's Owner. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: This works I followed some tutorial recommended above and added an IBOutlet from my tableview in XIB to my viewcontroller.m file... thank you all!